# lubuntu: Ubuntu 16.04.01 kernel (4.13.0-32-generic) kernel panic wifi not working

Tags: wireless, kernel, lubuntu, hp-pavilion

I am running lubuntu(Ubuntu 16.04.01) with kernel 4.13.0-32-generic on HP Pavilion dv6700 laptop PC. I have installed lubuntu in dual boot with my OEM windows installation.

After installing the OS, during boot process I have started observing kernel panic with the stack trace as shown below. Machine boots fine and I am able to login to desktop, however wifi is totally unresponsive.

Stack Trace:

- flush_workqueue+0xa/0x400
- ? ieee80211_restart_work+0x26/0xd0 [mac80211]
- process_one_work+0x156/0x410
- ...
- ...
- ...
- ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30

---

- RIP: mutex_lock+0x1d/ox40 RSP:ffff9690809cfd68
- CR2: 0000000000000020

Are there any known solutions for this?

Comment: Did you install `linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic` as well? It's needed for many wifi devices.

Comment: @Dorian I haven't installed linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic yet. I will try and confirm. However, I got linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic update a day before which is also giving me same problem. For now, I am relying on 4.13.0-28 kernel to boot up my laptop without any issues.

Comment: @Dorian I can see linux-image-extra 4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1 installed on my laptop, still no luck :(

Comment: You need to install the linux-image-extra package that matches the kernel you have installed.  The verions must match.  So if you have kernel 4.13.0-36 then you must have linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it after upgrade to latest LTS 18 version and disabling hp_wmi on my HP Pavilion dv6700 laptop PC

```
# echo "blacklist hp_wmi" > /etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf
```

After reading around multiple forums it looked like a wifi driver conflict between hp_wmi and intel generic driver for controlling onboard wifi chipset.

Reference:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169503